# Some questions about resources

Tags: arrays, vb.net, resources, my.resources

I am writing application that use resources, and I have some questions about it:

1. Can app-inside resources (my.resources) be edited, removed and added, and how can I do it?
2. How can I create an array of the app-inside resources?
3. How can I read an .resources file and turn it into an array of the items inside it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: In question #1, do you mean at run-time or at design-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded resources cannot be changed at run-time.  You can access them as a collection.  For instance:

```
' Get resource value by string name
Dim value1 As Object = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("name1")
Dim value2 As String = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("name2")

' Loop through list of resources
Dim rset As ResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, True, True)
For Each i As DictionaryEntry In rset
    Dim name As String = i.Key
    Dim value As Object = i.Value
Next
```

If you want to, at run-time, read and modify resources which are stored in an external `.resources` file, the .NET framework provides some classes in the `System.Resources` namespace which you can use.  The `ResourceReader` class allows you to read a `.resources` file, like this:

```
Using reader As New ResourceReader("test.resources")
    For Each i As DictionaryEntry In reader
        Dim name As String = i.Key
        Dim value As Object = i.Value
    Next
End Using
```

And you can use the `ResourceWriter` class to create a new `.resources` file, like this:

```
Using writer As New ResourceWriter("test.resources")
    writer.AddResource("name1", value1)
    writer.AddResource("name2", value2)
End Using
```

However, the real question to ask is, do you have to use `.resources` files?  Typically .resource files are only used as a assembly-building-step so that they can be embedded in the assembly.  If you want to store data in external files, typically you would choose to store them in some other format.  .NET provides many object serialization options which make it easy to store objects in XML, text, binary, or other types of files as well as databases.

Comment: Thank you. And how can I load a .resources file to my.resources?

Comment: Typically resources are compiled into the assembly.  Are you saying that you will be loading the resources dynamically at run-time from a `.resources` file?  If so, that changes things considerably.

Comment: Yes, I want to load them at runtime if that's possiable, and then I will be able to delete or add items from the .resources file and then restart the program.

Comment: That worked - thank you! I have only one question - when I try to save the resources, the following exception appears: "The process cannot access the file 'XYZ' because it is being used by another process." How can I save my resources without getting this exception?

Comment: Well, you won't be able to do it if the file is open.  First you'd need to determine who has the file open.  Is it your own process, or some other process that has it open and why?    When using the `ResourceReader`, the file should be closed when the `End Using` line is executed.

Comment: I sloved the problem - it was an IO operation with the file. Thank you again.